# How do I print only the selection from my list group item?

Tags: javascript, jquery, django-templates

I searched how to and I am not able to find an answer.

I have 3 list group boxes like this in my Web page
[Containers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HqHAD.png)

I am trying to write get the selection using jQuery/javascript for my right Container to print in my bottom container.

```
**My HTML**
<div class="col-6">
    <div class="card ">
        <div class="card-header py-2">LEFT CONTAINER</div>
        <div id="leftContainer" class="list-group" style="height:425px; overflow-y: scroll">
        <!-- POPULATED BY JINJA -->
        {% for campaign in campaign_histories %}
            <a href="#" data-set="{{ campaign_histories|length }}" id = "{{forloop.counter}}" class="list-group-item py-0 list-group-item-action">{{forloop.counter}}.  {{ campaign }}</a>
        {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-6">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header py-2">RIGHT CONTAINER</div>
        <div id="rightContainer" class="list-group" style="height:425px; overflow-y: scroll">
            <!-- POPULATED BY AJAX BELOW -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>                
<div class="col-12" >
    <div class="card mt-4" id="BOTTOM CONTAINER">
        <div class="card-header py-2">BOTTOM CONTAINER</div>
        <div id="bottonContainer" class="list-group" style="height:190px;">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<p id = "DEBUG"></p>  <!-- FOR DEBUG PRINT ONLY, REMOVE LATER-->
```

**My jQuery/AJAX:**

```
<script>
$("#leftContainer> a").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#leftContainer > a").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:"view_results/onclick/",
        data:{
            idx:index,
            csrfmiddlewaretoken:"{{ csrf_token }}"
        },
        dataType:"text json",
        success: function(resp){
            // console.log(resp.model_list);
            $("#rightContainer > a").removeClass("active");
            $("#rightContainer > a").hide();
            $("#rightContainer ").empty()
            success_flag =1;
            for(i=0; i<resp.model_list.length; i++){            
                $("#rightContainer ").append('<a href="#" id ='+i+' class="list-group-item list-group-item-success py-0 list-group-item-action">'+resp.model_list[i]+'</a>');
            }
        },
    })
});
</script>
```

I added THIS below to my scripts to debug print it to my `<p id = "DEBUG">` in my HTML. But it is printing the whole list. I do not know how to get the selection from my RIGHT CONTAINER to print. I need both the text and the index. :

```
$("#rightContainer").on('click',function(){        
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#rightContainer > a").removeClass("active");
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
        document.getElementById("debug").innerHTML = $(this).children().attr("id")
    });
```

My NEED is:
I only want to print to my BOTTOMCONTAINER ONLY the selection from my RIGHTCONTAINER instead of the whole list . I also need to add a button to the end of item printed in the bottom container. I am using bootstrap 4.

Can you help? My project is Django/Python in the backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is after your loop that appends all the links to the right container, you can add an on click listener on all the links you added (with a special class name to be specific).

Then in the function that handles the click event, you can use the `this` keyword to access the properties of the clicked link and use them to create your next element to append to the bottom container. Here is an example:

First you should add a class name for all the links in the right container so we know we are only targeting those. Notice below I only added `rightContainerLink` to the classes.

```
for(i=0; i<resp.model_list.length; i++){            
    $("#rightContainer ").append('<a href="#" id ='+i+' class="list-group-item list-group-item-success py-0 list-group-item-action rightContainerLink">'+resp.model_list[i]+'</a>');
}
```

Then you can go ahead and use that class selector to be sure you only run handleLinkClick when a rightContainer link is clicked.

```js
$(".rightContainerLink").on("click", handleLinkClick);

function handleLinkClick() {
  let index = $(this).attr("id");
  let text = $(this).text();
  let elem = `<span>index is: ${index} text is: ${text}</span>`;
  elem += "<button> I am a button</button> <br/>";
  $("#bottomContainer").append(elem);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="rightContainer">
  <a href="#" id='1' class="list-group-item list-group-item-success py-0 list-group-item-action rightContainerLink">model 1</a>
  <a href="#" id='2' class="list-group-item list-group-item-success py-0 list-group-item-action rightContainerLink">model 2</a>
  <a href="#" id='3' class="list-group-item list-group-item-success py-0 list-group-item-action rightContainerLink">model 3</a>

  <!-- This link will not add to the bottom div because it doesn't have rightContainerLink class -->
  <a href="#" id='4' class="list-group-item list-group-item-success py-0 list-group-item-action">I will not be added to bottom 4</a>
</div>
<hr/>
<div id="bottomContainer">
</div>
```

Comment: What does that `<hr/>` do? I have never seen something like that before. It worked.

Comment: Also, how do I bind the first "click" to only to the #rightContainer click and not to #leftContainer click? I tried `$("#rightContainer >a").on("click", handleLinkClick);` and that didn't work. My  Right container only populates when the Left container is clicked first (see first line of my script/jQuery in question above: `$("#leftContainer> a").click(function(event)`. So right now when I click first on the leftContainer, the bottom container is getting populated with index and text of the Left container instead of my Right Container which is what I want.

Comment: `<hr/>` is just a line break to show the difference between the 2 divs, its not needed.

Comment: You can add a class to all your links in the right container to be more specific about which links should be clicked. I'll update my example